# JPopupPanel closed when click on its JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpopupmenu

I have a `JPopupPanel` showing up when a button is clicked.

This `JPopupPanel` has a `JPopupMenu` which shows up with the mouse right click, showing different options. 
When left button pressed to choose one of this options in the PopupMenu, the PopupPanel closes leaving the PopupMenu by itself for a moment, and when the button is released, the PopupMenu also dissapears (as expected), but the action cannot be seen in the PopupPanel since it is already closed.

How can I avoid the JPopupPanel to close when choosing one of the options of the JPopupMenu?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I do not have experience using JPopupPanel. Thus, I can only offer a simple **hack**.

I would suspect that you can do something similar as in my example (below) where I 'ignore' hiding popup menu on an option select.

My approach here is to reshow the popup menu on an option selection. So fallowing this maybe you can try and reshow your panel when it hides.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPopupMenuIgnoreOptionCloseOnClick extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu("Oi I am popup");
    private MouseListener mL = new MouseAdapter()   
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mL mousePressed e.isP="+e.isPopupTrigger());
            super.mousePressed(e);
            showPopup(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {           
            System.out.println("mL mouseReleased e.isP="+e.isPopupTrigger());
            super.mouseReleased(e);
            showPopup(e);
        }

        private void showPopup(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.isPopupTrigger())
            {
                prevLocation = e.getPoint();
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    };
    private Point prevLocation = null;
    private MouseListener optionML = new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("optionML mouseReleased prevLocation="+prevLocation);
            e.consume();
            popup.show(JPopupMenuIgnoreOptionCloseOnClick.this, prevLocation.x,prevLocation.y);
        } 

    };

    public JPopupMenuIgnoreOptionCloseOnClick()
    {
        addMouseListener(mL);
        JMenuItem opt1 =new JMenuItem("Option 1");
        opt1.addMouseListener(optionML);
        popup.add(opt1);
        JMenuItem opt2 =new JMenuItem("Option 2");
        opt2.addMouseListener(optionML);
        popup.add(opt2);
        JMenuItem opt3 =new JMenuItem("Option 3");
        opt3.addMouseListener(optionML);
        popup.add(opt3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {           
                JPopupMenuIgnoreOptionCloseOnClick p = new JPopupMenuIgnoreOptionCloseOnClick();
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                contentPane.add(p);
                JFrame f = new JFrame();        
                f.setContentPane(contentPane);
                f.setSize(800, 600);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: @ Boro  +1  but hmmm (for futures readers) how to tell you respectable, finer ... you totally ignored EDT in main method, and examples about LayeredPane k*i*l*l*e*d  *** PrefferedSize for Container's childs, edit that and put there icon + button Preferred Size +10 for excelent output to the GUI, if you edit that, then this comment can be deleted :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for the comment. My ignorance of the EDT (when building GUI) is explained by me being lazy when coding a simple solutions/examples. Code was edited. I will try to add SwingUtilities.invokeLater() in every example from now on. BTW I have never seen a problem when GUI building ignoring EDT would cause problems on a simple example. For explanation why I used the setPreferredSize() for scroll panes see the note 2 under my answer. PS: no need to remove your comment --- it will be used as a reminder.

Comment: "BTW I have never seen a problem when GUI building ignoring EDT " 1/ yes untill/then you'll try to aply some original L&F, nor Custom,   2/ one time (I wish you that) you'll userPower not 0.6T but 6T, and then any newbee could take this one as coding standard,   3/ <:-)> some peoples here wouldn't take setSize() just as lazyness </:-)>

Comment: @mKorbel good points. Understood. The code with scrolls now also includes GUI building on EDT. If it goes to why I use setSize on componentRezised is that setPrefferedSize doesn't work. Not very sure why probably because of the components being children of the layered pane.

Comment: @ Boro     :-)   how to get out of it now out   :-)                         for EDT issue just pack() plus Visible

Comment: sure don't do it something with your Updates

Comment: @mKorbel can you please clarify your last comment? What shouldn't I do with which updates?

Comment: nothing, absolutely nothing, for EDT is relevant pack() or ( for AbsoluteLayout ) setSize(), when Container obtained real screenSize (LayoutManager) and thenafter for Containers visibility,

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem myself when installing a custom JPopupMenu on a JCommandButton.
For your JCommandButton I found this to be helpful in preventing premature disposal of the parent popup:

```
this.putClientProperty(BasicCommandButtonUI.DONT_DISPOSE_POPUPS, true);
```

If what you are looking for is instead that upon making a JPopupMenu JMenuItem selection, the parent popup panel will stay open, you have a couple options.  The problem stems from JPopupMenu's broken link in the ancestry container chain, on which the UI relies.  Instead of getParent(), you need to return getInvoker().

1:
modify the library source in BasicPopupPanelUI.WindowTracker.eventDispatched().  Either change the **SwingUtilities**.getAncestorOfClass() calls to use **SwingXUtilities**.getAncestorOfClass() which accounts for this special case.  Or implement the logic yourself.

```
if(parent instanceof JPopupMenu)  parent = ((JPopupMenu)parent).getInvoker()
```

2:

Add this code to the widget (CustomButton?)

```
 final JPopupMenu popper = new JPopupMenu(){  //hack
        @Override public Container getParent(){
            StackTraceElement ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
            if(ste.getClassName().equals(SwingUtilities.class.getName()))
                return CustomButton.this.getParent();
            return super.getParent();
        }
    };
```

I chose #2, since I have issues with modifying 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Finally I (well, I got some outside help) did something like what you suggest: override the SubstancePopupPanelUI class so in the inner class WindowTracker2 you can do the hack inside the eventDispatched method by checking the SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass() from Swingx

Thanks anyway